# Trouble understanding Maven Surefire plugin's parallel parameters

Tags: maven, cucumber, maven-surefire-plugin

Quoting from [maven.apache.org](https://maven.apache.org/components/surefire-archives/surefire-2.22.1/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/fork-options-and-parallel-execution.html):

> ... the parallel parameter. The possible values depend on the test
>   provider used. For JUnit 4.7 and onwards, this may be methods,
>   classes, both, suites, suitesAndClasses, suitesAndMethods,
>   classesAndMethods or all

I just want to execute Cucumber feature files in parallel. What do these parameters--main, methods, classes, etc.-- mean in this context?  Here's an excerpt from my pom.xml file:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M4</version>
            <configuration>
                **<parallel>methods</parallel>**
                <useUnlimitedThreads>true</useUnlimitedThreads>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I just put 'methods' in the parallel tag because the guide on Cucumber's [Parallel Execution page](https://cucumber.io/docs/guides/parallel-execution/) used this configuration. I have no idea *why* they chose to configure it this way. Why didn't they choose other options like 'classes' or 'classesAndMethods'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a really good question! I am one of the implementer of support for parallel execution in Cucumber and it actually took me quite a while to work this all out.

JUnit, Surefire and Cucumber have evolved together. So certain concepts were initially introduced with a narrow focus that was later generalized but not renamed. As a result you run into these rather odd mismatches.

So JUnit represents tests as a simple tree:

```
Example1Test.class
 |- method1()
 |- method2()
 |- method3()
Example2Test.class
 |- method1()
 |- method2()
 |- method3()
```

Because JUnit initially didn't have parallel execution this was handled by surefire. Surefire would start multiple instances of JUnit and divide the classes that should be tested between them.

JUnit added support for parallel execution down to method level by adding `setScheduler(RunnerScheduler scheduler)` to test executors. Once this was present, surefire had to distinguish between using its own parallel execution method, junits parallel execution method or both. Hence the different options and their names.

At some point in time JUnit also added support for implementing custom runners. Cucumber uses this implements a custom runner. And to JUnit this looks like this:

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
RunCucumberTest.class
|- Feature1
|  |- scenario1()
|- Feature2
|  |- scenario1()
|  |- scenario2()
```

To execute features in parallel JUnit has to use `setScheduler(scheduler)` method on the executor (`Cucumber.class`). To do this JUnit has to be instructed by Surefire to use a parallel scheduler. And the way we do this is by telling Surefire to use the `methods` option.

Now this is a rather high level explanation and you can zoom in much more by looking at the source code:

- https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/blob/master/junit/src/main/java/io/cucumber/junit/Cucumber.java
- https://github.com/apache/maven-surefire/blob/master/surefire-providers/surefire-junit47/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/surefire/junitcore/JUnitCoreProvider.java
- https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/blob/master/src/main/java/org/junit/runner/JUnitCore.java
- https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/blob/master/src/main/java/org/junit/runners/ParentRunner.java

Comment: Can you execute tests in parallel with JUnit alone or do you need Surefire as well?

Comment: With JUnit 4, it's possible but complicated. With JUnit 5 it is simpler. Youll have to use Cucumbers JUnit Platform Engine: https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/master/junit-platform-engine

Comment: Then you can use the JUnit Console Launcher to run the tests.